# Term for Major Scale with a minor seventh

Tags: scales, terminology, key

Given a C major Scale, with **C as root**:

C D E F G A B

now make the 7th. step *minor*, and keeping **C as root**
(*not* switching to F Major)

C D E F G A Bb

What is the term / name for this key?

Comment: Thanks for adding a question and an accurate answer! I’m voting to close this question for the future, just because it's a basic piece of reference knowledge that can be obtained elsewhere with more context. I hope you stick around, and check out [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Check out my animated mode wheel here: https://b-p-thomas.github.io/   When this first displays it shows C Ionian, but if you click the [>] button once, it will flatten the B to Bb, and indicate that you're now playing C Mixolydian instead of C Ionian. Enjoy.

Comment: Brian, that animated mode wheel app works fantastically. very illustrative - understanding by geometry makes it so much easier. Thanks a bunch! Greetings & Happy Jamming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I think the answer is:

It is **C Mixolydian**.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is C mixolydian.

The formula for mixolydian scales is WWHWWHW, so if you put it on c it wI'll be like that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the term / name for this key?

The **key** is C major, because the chord built on the first step is C major. Or to be more specific, it's *most probably* C major, as I presume in your composition C major chord would function as a tonic chord, the chord resolving the tension.

The **scale**, as the others said is C mixolydian.

As you noticed C mixolydian has the same notes as F major scale. It is a called a *mode* of F major. As the F major scale has 7 notes, it has seven modes: F ionian (same as F major scale), G dorian, A phrygian, Bb lydian, C mixolydian, D aeolian and E locrian.

Answer (score 3):

Modes work from *parent* keys/scales. The parent for that set of notes is *F major*.

The 5th mode of F major, using C as the root, is the Mixolydian **of**  F, more often called C Mixolydian. Not so much a key (as you thought), but as a 'scale', properly known as a mode.